# why the contend of tab1 not show in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have tab bar in angular using foundation.css file.My problem is that when I run my program it not show tab1 contend or when I click tab1 it not show any thing but when I click tab2 or tab3 or tab4 it show it contend .but why it is not showing tab1 contend.Secondly how to add active class when user click any of tab ?

here is plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/He6GsvQkehGRLfzoEJb0?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.x" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.x" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/o21mnbgjar28cfv/foundation.css?dl=0" />

    <script data-require="jquery@2.1.1" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@0.10.0" data-semver="0.10.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
<div ng-app="">
    <dl class="tabs" data-tab>
        <dd class='main.value="Tab1"'><a>Tab 1</a></dd>
        <dd><a ng-click='main.value="Tab2"'>Tab 2</a></dd>
        <dd><a ng-click='main.value="Tab3"'>Tab 3</a></dd>
        <dd><a ng-click='main.value="Tab4"'>Tab 4</a></dd>
    </dl>
    <div class="tabs-content">
        <div ng-switch="main.value">
        <div class="content" ng-switch-when="Tab1">
            <p>This is the first panel of the basic tab example. This is the first panel of the basic tab example.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="content" ng-switch-when="Tab2">
            <p>This is the second panel of the basic tab example. This is the second panel of the basic tab example.</p>
        </div >
        <div class="content" ng-switch-when="Tab3">
            <p>This is the third panel of the basic tab example. This is the third panel of the basic tab example.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="content" ng-switch-when="Tab4">
            <p>This is the fourth panel of the basic tab example. This is the fourth panel of the basic tab example.</p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `ng-click` to the first tab as well:

```
<a ng-click='main.value="Tab1"'>Tab 1</a>
```

To add the *active* class, use the `ng-class` directive:

```
<dd ng-class="{ active: main.value=='Tab1'}"><a ng-click='main.value="Tab1"'>Tab 1</a></dd>
<dd ng-class="{ active: main.value=='Tab2'}"><a ng-click='main.value="Tab2"'>Tab 2</a></dd>
<dd ng-class="{ active: main.value=='Tab3'}"><a ng-click='main.value="Tab3"'>Tab 3</a></dd>
<dd ng-class="{ active: main.value=='Tab4'}"><a ng-click='main.value="Tab4"'>Tab 4</a></dd>
```

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wwF5qJ4WFMDj0Qx0Albz?p=preview)**

Comment: thanks your answer is correct can you explain what is mean ng-class="{ active: main.value=='Tab1'}"

Comment: there is class in css samr thing is ng-class in angular why it is assined object.I sa vedio same thing in that do but not given why they do this

Comment: ng-class="{ active: main.value=='Tab1'}"..from that I think you add active class but why the value of active class is this main.value=='Tab4'

Comment: The "active" class is added if the expression returns true. So if `main.value` equals `'Tab1'`, then `active: true`. Check this [Angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass).

Comment: @bmlite do you know any idea of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25722401/how-to-search-and-highlight-in-angular-js/25723950#25723950

Answer (score 1):

Just initialize the value of `main.value` to `Tab1`:

```
ng-init='main.value="Tab1"'
```

Additionally add a ng-class element for highlighting the current tab:

```
ng-class="{ active: main.value=='Tab1'}"
```

Here is the working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tElrdQyqwvdlwcZCwROV?p=preview)

Comment: hoe to add active class so that we will differentiate on which tab it is click

Comment: can you please explain what is mean "{ active: main.value=='Tab1'}".from this I think you add active class but why u assign this value  main.value=='Tab1'

Comment: This means that the class `active` is added to the `dd` element if `main.value` has the value `Tab1`

Comment: boindil do you any idea of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25722401/how-to-search-and-highlight-in-angular-js/25723950#25723950

Comment: what do you want to know about this answer?

Comment: yes if you know better answer please post ..I have same problem solve this  with simple idea to search text and highlight

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60825/discussion-between-user944513-and-boindiil).